# How to join same table on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

What would be the best way to `JOIN` a table based on whether join column is `NULL` or not.

I need to `JOIN` table `#main` with table `#sub`.

For example:

if `ID` column in table `#main` is `NULL` then join on column `LocationID` = #sub.LocationID

if `ID` and `LocationID` columns in table `#main` is `NULL`s then join on column `UserID` = `#sub.UserID`

```
create table #main (ID int, locationID varchar(50), UserID varchar(50))
insert into #main values (1,'Loc1',NULL),
                         (2,NULL,'User1'),
                         (NULL,'Loc1','User1'),
                         (4,'Loc1',NULL),
                         (5,NULL,'User1'),
                         (NULL,'Loc1','User1')
--select * from #main


select *
from #main m
-- if m.ID is not null then join on m.ID  
-- OR if m.ID is null then join on m.locationID = s.LocationID  
-- OR if m.ID is null and m.LocationID is null then join on  m.UserID = s.UserID
    left join #sub s ON  m.ID = s.ID OR m.locationID = s.LocationID OR m.UserID = s.UserID
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Not sure about performance...

```
Select * From #Main m 
    left Join #sub s on 
    (m.id is null and m.locationid is null and m.userId = s.userID) 
    or (m.id is not null and m.locationid is null and m.locationid = s.locationId) 
    or (m.id is not null and m.locationid is not  null and m.id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want `join` or `left join` (you referred to both in your question), so modify the code below as fits your needs:

```
select  ...
from    #main  m
join    #sub   s  on m.id = s.id
                     or (m.id is null and and m.locationId = s.locationId)
                     or (m.id is null and m.locationId is null and m.userId = s.userId)
```

I have used a feature of `null` here to shorten the syntax: `null` is not equal to anything. It's not even equal to `null`. So when doing the join on the `m.id` column, it might seem like you have to do this:

```
on m.id is not null and m.id = s.id
```

But if `m.id` is null, then it will never equal `s.id`, because `null` is not equal to anything. And so you can just do

```
on m.id = s.id
```

Because that condition can only be met when `m.id` is not `null`. I have used a similar dirty trick for the `locationId` join condition.

However, joins containing `or` conditions are often very slow, and it is sometimes helpful to explain to SQL Server that this same problem can be phrased in terms of `union` operations where the joins contain no `or` operations, only `and` operations:

```
select    ...
from      #main  m
join      #sub   s on m.id = s.id
union all
select    ...
from      #main  m
join      #sub   s on m.id is null 
                      and m.locationId = s.locationId
union all
select    ...
from      #main  m
join      #sub   s on m.id is null 
                      and m.locationId is null 
                      and m.userId = s.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a query for each condition and union the results, something like

```
select * 
from #main m
left join #sub s on s.locationId = m.LocationId
where m.Id is null and m.locationId is not null
union all
select * 
from #main m
left join #sub s on s.UserId - m.UserId
where m.Id is null and m.locationId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to `join`, this can be done using `outer apply` with a subquery in which the matching condition is implemented via `case when` like this:

```
Select *
From #main As m Outer Apply 
(Select * From #sub As s 
 Where 1 = Case When m.ID Is Not Null And m.ID=s.ID Then 1
                When m.ID Is Null And m.LocationID Is Not Null And m.locationID=s.locationID Then 1
                When m.ID Is Null And m.LocationID Is Null And m.UserID Is Not Null And m.UserID=s.UserID Then 1
                Else 0
           End) As t
Order by m.ID, m.locationID, m.UserID
```